# Config file did not return an array

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

Currently upgrading a project from CakePHP2 to CakePHP4 and I received the error `Config file "tmi.php" did not return an array`.

This is how I'm importing it into `bootstrap.php`:

```
try {
    Configure::config('default', new PhpConfig());
    Configure::load('app', 'default', false);
    Configure::load('tmi', 'default');
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    exit($e->getMessage() . "\n");
}
```

This is an example of what the file contains:

```
Configure::write('weburl', 'https://weburl.net/');
Configure::write(
    'S3',
    [
        "bucket" => "bucketName",
        "key" => "bucketKey",
        "secret" => "bucketSecret",
    ]
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message suggests, PHP config files for `Configure::load()` must return an array now.

You can always check [**the current app template**](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/4.4.2/config/app.php) to figure how things are supposed to look like.

```php
return [
    // ...

    'weburl' => 'https://weburl.net/',

    'S3' => [
        "bucket" => "bucketName",
        "key" => "bucketKey",
        "secret" => "bucketSecret",
    ],
];
```